# Improving Telekinetic Hurl's range

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Can you use the following to improve the Psion Discipline Ability: Telekinetic Hurl effective range or is 30 feet the maximum for this ability and does not follow range increment rules?

> Telekinetic Hurl (Su) At 2nd level, as long as you maintain psionic
>   focus, you gain the ability to telekinetically hurl objects of up to 5
>   lbs. as a ranged attack at an enemy within 30 ft. Such attacks deal
>   1d4 points of damage due to the force exerted. This damage increases
>   by 1d4 points of damage for every four psion levels thereafter.

with

> Distance Thrower (Combat) Prerequisite: Str 13. Benefit: With a thrown
>   weapon, you reduce your penalty on ranged attack rolls due to range by
>   2.
>
> Throw Anything (Combat) Benefit: You do not suffer any penalties for
>   using an improvised ranged weapon. You receive a +1 circumstance bonus
>   on attack rolls made with thrown splash weapons. Normal: You take a –4
>   penalty on attack rolls made with an improvised weapon

Answer (score 3):

#### Ranged and thrown weapons typically have range increments; another effect must say it has a range increment to have one

The [psychokinesis discipline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/psionics-unleashed/classes/psion/psionic-disciplines/psychokinesis/) telekinetic hurl, a supernatural ability, has a maximum range of 30 ft. As a supernatural ability, it follows the rules for [magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/) unless it says otherwise, and, in this case, there's no indication that it breaks those rules, and that means the effect's limited to the stated [range](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/#TOC-Range). (You can read more about range increments and ranged and thrown weapons by searching for `Melee and Ranged Weapons` [here](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/weapons/).)

In short, the supernatural ability telekinetic hurl only does what it says it does, and feats like [Distance Thrower](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/distance-thrower-combat/) and [Throw Anything](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/throw-anything-combat-final/) (that have benefits applying to thrown weapon) have no effect on the ability.